# Existe alguma forma de converter uma string para base 64 em javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64

Existe alguma forma de converter uma string para base 64 em javascript?

No PHP podemos fazer assim:

```
base64_encode('stack overlow'); //c3RhY2sgb3Zlcmxvdw==
```

Como posso fazer isso em javascript?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92795/como-converter-uma-string-para-base64-em-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A resposta moderna é sim, com a função nativa [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa), disponível nos browsers modernos.

`btoa` quer dizer base para asci, e existe o oposto que é `atob`.

Nesse caso seria:

```
btoa('stack overlow'); // "c3RhY2sgb3Zlcmxvdw=="
```

Em browsers mais antigos isso não é tão simples e nesse caso sugiro uma função mais complexa, [tipo esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246813/2256325).

Mesmo em browsers modernos, há caracteres que podem fazer quebrar a função nativa `btoa()` como por exemplo:

```
btoa('✓ à la mode'); // Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
```

Nesses casos é preciso fazer escape/conversão desses caracteres. Na MDN sugerem estas funções:

```
function utf8_to_b64(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

function b64_to_utf8(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}
```

Mais info <sup>(em Inglês)</sup> [aqui na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding). Nesse artigo há também uma solução para caracteres que o `escape()` trata. Uma vez que o `escape()` está deprecado desde sempre (desde a ECMAScript v3 mas na verdade nunca foi removido) pode ser caso de usar uma alternativa). Aqui fica:

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

b64EncodeUnicode('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
```

Answer (score 6):

O método [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) pode fazer o encode pra você, assim como o [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) faz o decode. O retorno de

```
window.btoa('minha string')
```

é

> bWluaGEgc3RyaW5n

e o retorno de

```
window.atob('bWluaGEgc3RyaW5n')
```

é, como de se esperar

> minha string

**EDIT**

Como apontado pelo [Omni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8113/omni), ambos os métodos não tem suporte pra [versões anteriores ao IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=atob-btoa) (sempre ele).

Comment: Tenha em atenção que `atob` e `btoa` [não são suportados por versões anteriores ao IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=atob-btoa).

Comment: Achei estranho o nome da função. Existe algum significado específico para esse nome? Acho que no PHP ficou mais descritivo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters para seguir a convencao do C (como por exemplo `atoi`). Neste caso `atob` significa *ascii to base64*.

Comment: Essa informação foi muito importante @Omni

Answer (score 3):

Tal como mencionado, `atob` e `btoa` não funcionam em versões anteriores ao IE10.

Pode para isso fazer a sua própria função de conversão (retirada [daqui](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript_base64.html)):

```js
var Base64 = {
  _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
  encode: function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;
      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }
      output = output + this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output;
  },
  decode: function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
    while (i < input.length) {
      enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
      chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
      chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
      output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
      if (enc3 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
      }
      if (enc4 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
      }
    }
    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);
    return output;
  },
  _utf8_encode: function(string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
      var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      } else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    }
    return utftext;
  },
  _utf8_decode: function(utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = c1 = c2 = 0;
    while (i < utftext.length) {
      c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
      if (c < 128) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(c);
        i++;
      } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
        i += 2;
      } else {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
        i += 3;
      }
    }
    return string;
  }
}

$encoded = Base64.encode("pt.stackoverflow.com");
alert($encoded)
$decoded = Base64.decode($encoded)
alert($decoded)
```

Comment: Que paranauezão para fazer um base64. Viva o IE!