# Como converter uma string para base64 em Python?

Tags: python

Sou iniciando em `Python` e venho do `PHP`.

Para converter uma string em base 64 no PHP, eu faço da seguinte forma:

```
base64_encode('stack overflow'); //c3RhY2sgb3ZlcmZsb3c=
```

E no `Python`, como faço isso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92791/existe-alguma-forma-de-converter-uma-string-para-base-64-em-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É parecido. Tem que apenas fazer um `import`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(b'stack overflow')
b'c3RhY2sgb3ZlcmZsb3c='
```

`b64encode` pede um array de bytes, não uma *string*. O `b` na frente faz essa conversão.

Comment: Por que você usou `b'stack'` ao invés de só `'stack'`? binary?

Comment: Porque `b64encode` pede um array de bytes, não uma string. O `b` na frente faz essa conversão.